# Sql query to group by and merge rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on sql query with table structure like below

```
col1    col2    col3
1        nik    NULL
1        nik1   NULL
1        NULL   mah
1        NULL   mah1
```

Now i want output like

```
col1    col2    col3
    1   nik     mah
    1   nik1    mah1
```

So i want to merge null values if there is value in col2 or col3

How can i achieve this ??

EDIT :Main structure is if col2 has values then col3 will be null and if col3 has value then col2 will be null

So i want to reduce the total no of rows by filling up null values

Comment: With which rule do you link `nik` with `mah` and `nik1` with `mah1` ?

Comment: that if col2 or col3 has equal non nullable values then total no of rows should be merged and null values should be filled with non nullable values

Comment: Ok I understand that, but how do you choose the values to merge? I mean, can `nik` be merged with `mah1`? Or is there a real rule to choose how to merge lines.

Comment: Could you please read the main thread.. i just edited with more clear explanation...hope it clear ur doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T2.Col3
FROM
(SELECT Col1,Col2,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Col1) as RN
 FROM TableName
 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL) T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Col1,Col3,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Col1) as RN
 FROM TableName
 WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL) T2 ON T1.Col1=T2.Col1 AND T1.RN=T2.RN
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/409e3/8).